# .NET Core 3.0 - Cannot find nuget packages related with Identity

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I use Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition and I create ASP.NET Core web application. I choose individual user accounts authentication and I receive the following error when I try to run the project;

```
Error   NU1102  Unable to find package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore with version (>= 3.0.0)
Error   NU1102  Unable to find package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools with version (>= 3.0.0)
Error   NU1102  Unable to find package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer with version (>= 3.0.0)
Error   NU1102  Unable to find package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore with version (>= 3.0.0)
```

What I tried is :

1. Update Nuget - it is written that I should 'click in Tools menu -> Extensions and Updates -> Updates -> Visual Studio Gallery'  but in community version I don't have that menu
2. I installed .NET Core SDK 3 and .NET Core runtime

Comment: Please try executing the command: `dotnet restore` under your project folder.

Comment: Have you try to add package through commend line?